# Rails order by association being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to order by two columns, one is an association column which is being ignored, not implemented. Is it possible to order by association in a loop?

**Loop**

```
<% @info.each do |data| %>
 <% data.selections.size.times do |i| %>
  <% unless data.progressions.blank? %>
    <% data.progressions.order_scope.in_groups_of(7)[i].each_with_index do |e, index| %>
    <% if index == 0 %>
      <%= e.selection.name rescue 0 %>
    <% end %>
    <%= Time.at(e.assessment.date/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") rescue 0 %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Model**

```
belongs_to :selection, primary_key: 'selection_id', foreign_key: 'selection_id', optional: true
belongs_to :assessment, primary_key: 'assessment_id', optional: true

scope :order_scope, -> { order('selection_id').joins(:assessment).order('assessments.date') }
```

This is the output the previous code outputs, which seems to be randomly placing the dates instead of in order.

```
|name 1|     0    |0|0|0|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|23/01/2018|

|name 2|28/02/2018|0|0|0|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|21/01/2018|
```

Comment: You are using two orders. I don´t know the resulting sql statement. What if you change for: `-> { joins(:assessment).order('selection_id, assessments.date') }`?

Comment: Thanks Pablo, Still the same results.

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing your models. Does each `progression` have a unique `selection_id`?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the model.

Comment: Have you tried `reorder` instead of `order`. It is possible that you have already ordered it earlier, in which case `reorder` will be needed. Failing that, you can try to explicitly specify the ascending or descending e.g. `-> { joins(:assessment).order('selection_id ASC, assessments.date ASC') }`. Telling us the resulting SQL will also help you get an answer if the problem persists.

Comment: What is the generated SQL?

Comment: I'd suggest `scope :order_scope, -> { joins(:assessment).reorder('progressions.selection_id ASC, assessments.date ASC') }` as a brute force/cover all the bases option. 

I'd also be interested in seeing what the other models look like given the explicit primary and foreign key assignments you have - perhaps there is a disconnect/mixup with the associations.

Comment: Please provide the output of `@info.first.progressions.order_scope.to_sql`, e.g. via `Rails.logger` in your controller before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because progressions could have the same `selection_id`,when you order them, the result can be different. Try adding another unique attribute/column into the `order`, for example `created_at` or `id`, so that the order is always unique.

```
scope :order_scope, -> { order('selection_id, created_at').joins(:assessment).order('assessments.date') }
```